# psycopg2 programming error while creating table

Tags: psycopg2

In a Python2.7 script, the following gave me an error, I can't figure out why:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=mydb user=username password=password")
curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE newtable;")
```

The error looks like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-17-f4ba0186c40c>", line 1, in <module>
    curs.execute("CREATE TABLE newtable;")

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE newtable;
```

Any `SELECT` statement works perfectly well on the other hand. For example:

```
curs.execute("SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 0;")
```

works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE newtable;` is not the correct syntax to create a new table. You need to define some columns.

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (
    foo INTEGER,
    bar TEXT
);
```

See [the CREATE TABLE docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createtable.html) for more info.

Comment: Oh, pretty annoying... Is it possible to easily copy the "structure" of another table and adding only a few new columns instead of writing down tens of columns names and data types?

Comment: This is an example for copying the structure from another table;    
`CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE 1=0;`